# Final-tagless encoding of mutually recursive types

Tags: haskell, typeclass, functional-dependencies

I am trying to express a pair of mutually recursive data types in the `final-tagless` encoding.

I am able to write:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForAll #-}
module Test where

  class ExprSYM repr where
    expr :: forall proc. (ProcSYM proc) => proc Int -> repr

  class ProcSYM repr where
    varProc :: forall a. String -> repr a
    intProc :: String -> repr Int
    subjectOf :: forall expr. (ExprSYM expr) => expr -> repr Int

  myProc = intProc "proc A."
```

However, when I write:

```
myExpr = expr myProc
```

I receive the following error:

```
Could not deduce (Test.ProcSYM proc0)
  arising from a use of ‘Test.expr’
from the context (Test.ExprSYM repr)
  bound by the inferred type of
           Test.myExpr :: Test.ExprSYM repr => repr
  at src/Test.hs:16:3-22
The type variable ‘proc0’ is ambiguous
In the expression: Test.expr Test.myProc
In an equation for ‘Test.myExpr’:
    Test.myExpr = Test.expr Test.myProc
```

Does any such encoding require the use of functional dependencies (or equivalent) to expess the constraint between the two `representation` types?

If so, how would I write this?

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `expr :: (forall proc. (ProcSYM proc) => proc Int) -> repr`?

Comment: This works (with RankNTypes) but I'm not sure why?

Comment: David Young: that's a typo; I'll edit.

Comment: Unrelated: I highly recommend avoiding `ExplicitForAll` and instead using `ScopedTypeVariables` in all modules that use type system extensions. This will prevent you from accidentally writing anything that will break when you decide to use scoped type variables somewhere. It also tends to make type errors and typed holes more useful.

Comment: dfeuer: Thanks for that. I had included the explicit `forall`s as I originally tried to write this in Purescript where they are mandatory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start by looking at the type of `myProc`

```
myProc :: ProcSYM repr => repr Int
myProc = intProc "proc A."
```

This says, `forall` types `repr` where `ProcSYM repr`, I'm a value of type `repr Int`. If we had multiple implementations of `ProcSYM`, this is a value that's polymorphic in all of them. For example, if we had a corresponding tagged `GADT` `ProcSYM'` with a `ProcSYM` instance, `myProc` could be used as a value of `ProcSYM'`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data ProcSYM' a where
    VarProc :: String -> ProcSYM' a
    IntProc :: String -> ProcSYM' a

instance ProcSYM ProcSYM' where
    varProc = VarProc
    intProc = IntProc

myProc' :: ProcSYM' Int
myProc' = myProc
```

The `ProcSym repr` constraint in `myProc :: ProcSYM repr => repr Int` is providing a way to *construct* `repr`s, which is exactly what `myProc` does. No matter which `ProcSym repr` you want, it can construct a `repr Int`.

The `ProcSYM proc` constraint in the type of `expr :: forall proc. (ProcSYM proc) => proc Int -> repr` is kind of meaningless. The constraint `ProcSYM proc` is once again providing a means to construct `proc`s. It can't help us look inside or *deconstruct* a `proc Int`. Without a way to look inside `proc Int`s, we might as well not have the `proc Int` argument and instead read `expr :: repr`.

The type `forall proc. ProcSYM proc => proc Int` (the type of `myProc`) on the other hand, promises, no matter how you construct `proc`s, I can provide a value of that type. You want to pass `myProc` as the first argument to `expr`, as evidenced by

```
myExpr = expr myProc
```

Passing in a polymorphic value of this type without choosing a concrete `proc` requires `RankNTypes`.

```
class ExprSYM repr where
    expr :: (forall proc. ProcSYM proc => proc Int) -> repr
```

The instance for `ExprSYM` can choose the `ProcSYM` dictionary to pass into the first argument. This allows the implementation of `expr` to deconstruct the `proc Int`. We'll demonstrate this by completing an example with `GADTs` to see what this is doing. We will also make the same change to the type of `subjectOf`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
module Test where

class ExprSYM repr where
    expr :: (forall proc. ProcSYM proc => proc Int) -> repr

class ProcSYM repr where
    varProc :: forall a. String -> repr a
    intProc :: String -> repr Int
    subjectOf :: (forall expr. ExprSYM expr => expr) -> repr Int

-- Tagged representation for ExprSYM
data ExprSYM' where
    Expr :: ProcSYM' Int -> ExprSYM'
deriving instance Show ExprSYM'

instance ExprSYM ExprSYM' where
    expr x = Expr x  -- chooses that the ProcSYM proc => proc Int must be ProcSYM' Int

-- Tagged representation for ProcSYM
data ProcSYM' a where
    VarProc :: String -> ProcSYM' a
    IntProc :: String -> ProcSYM' a
    SubjectOf :: ExprSYM' -> ProcSYM' Int

deriving instance Show (ProcSYM' a)

instance ProcSYM ProcSYM' where
    varProc = VarProc
    intProc = IntProc
    subjectOf x = SubjectOf x  -- chooses that the ExprSYM repr => repr must be ExprSYM'

-- myProc and myExpr with explicit type signatures
myProc :: ProcSYM repr => repr Int
myProc = intProc "proc A."

myExpr :: ExprSYM repr => repr
myExpr = expr myProc

main = print (myExpr :: ExprSYM')
```

This outputs an abstract syntax tree for `myExpr`. We can see that if the implementation of `expr` wanted to deconstruct the `ProcSYM proc => proc Int` value it could (and in this case did) provide a `ProcSYM` dictionary that builds values it knows how to deconstruct. We can see this in the `IntProc` constructor in the shown value.

```
Expr (IntProc "proc A.")
```

Comment: Thank you for this very clear explanation. Am I correct in thinking that this is an example of an existential type?